# What is the opposite of higher in "Bounce me higher"?

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

Normal opposite of higher is lower. But in this case will it make sense to say "Bounce me lower"?

Situation:

My child loves it when her father bounces her. She says "Bounce me higher".

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean? When would you want to say this?

Comment: @sumelic added situation

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes sense. Alternative phrasing is

> don't bounce me that/so high.

Comment: "bounce me lower" sounds very weird. Your suggestion "don't bounce me that/so high." sounds perfect. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about height, then higher and lower definitely makes sense.

But even in this case, they make sense, if you view it from another angle.

Bounce me lower(than I am now) does not make any sense. If I'm standing at a height of 4 feet, I can bounce my child to 5 feet, or to 6 feet, but not to say, 3 feet.

But it makes sense when it's meant as - bounce me lower(than you're doing now). So, bounce me lower(to 5 feet) than you're doing now(to 6 feet).

It's unconventional, but legal.